# How to add total number of pages on a book reference with natbib

Tags: cross-referencing, natbib

I want to get my book references with the total number of pages displayed at the end, like this:

A.G.I., y Howell, J., 1960, Glossary of geology and related sciences: A cooperative project
of the american geological institute: Washington D.C., American Geological Institute, **397 pp.**

But instead I got this:

A.G.I., y Howell, J., 1960, Glossary of geology and related sciences: A cooperative project
of the american geological institute: Washington D.C., American Geological Institute.

I've already add the field pagetotal to the reference in the .bib file, like this:

```
    @book{agi1960,
   Author = {A.G.I. and Howell, J.V.},
   Title = {Glossary of Geology and Related Sciences: A Cooperative Project of the American Geological Institute},
   Publisher = {American Geological Institute},
   Address = {Washington D.C.},
      Year = {1960},
   Pagetotal = {397} }
```

Additionaly, I've tried to add the field to the .bst file, guessing that remplacing pages output with pagetotal output, but it didn't work.

```
FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
      editor format.key output
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
  add.colon
      format.edition output
      format.number.series output
      format.publisher.address output
    }
    {
  add.colon
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.book.pages output
  format.doi output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
```

I've read something like that I need to use biblatex to get the field "pagetotal" working on, but currently I'm using natbib. Is there a way to get it?

Comment: Usually one just uses the `pages` field in `bibtex` for this.  But without more details of which bibliography style you are using, a concrete answer can not be given.